# Regex position string

Tags: regex, string

For example i have this string.

```
$string = 'test***bas';
```

How can I display text before the stars with Regex?

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes please share it with us.

Comment: My guess is that this could be php? not really sure given the information only available in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tou also want what is located after the ***, you can use the following:

```
$string = 'test***bas';
$pattern = '/(.+)\*{3}(.+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

$matches will contain the results:

$matches[1] will be "test"
$matches[2] will be "bas"

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern

```
^(.+?)\*\*\*
```

will create a group match using the parenthesis operators. See http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for testing your regular expressions (there are many ways of testing online)

The language you use around your regular expression will have different ways of capturing groups so you will need to better explain what language you are using for any further advice.

**Example for before and after asterix**

```
^(.+?)\*\*\*(.+)$
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, the last section of your regex, `\*\*\*` can be changed to `\*{3}` ;)

Comment: +1 Good spot, always lots of ways of doing things with regular expressions :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression which makes use of [Capture Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). Once that you have matched your input, you could then access the captured group and print the output.